# ruby 2.2. : passing parameter to SQL request string in config yaml file

Tags: ruby, yaml

given a config file config.yml

```
# config.yml
folders:
   tree: 
    top: "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = 'alpha'"
    bottom: "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = '#{name}'"
```

when I execute in a ruby script :

```
# myscript1.rb
@config = YAML::load_file File.join( @rundir, 'config.yml')
....
@db.execute(@config['folders']['tree']['top'])
```

the db select is correctly executed ..
how should I write my ruby command to run the second request passing 'name' as a parameter ?

```
# myscript2.rb
@config = YAML::load_file File.join( @rundir, 'config.yml')
....
name = "beta"
@db.execute(@config['folders']['tree']['bottom']) # need parameter ?
```

thanks for help

Comment: If you want your question to be considered seriously, then ask seriously; use correct punctuation and capitalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Ruby DB interfaces I'm familiar with, you can pass arguments to `execute` that will be SQL escaped and interpolated into the query at points marked by `?`. So, first you want to rewrite the query to: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = ?;`. Then, you can call `@db.execute(@config['folders']['tree']['bottom'], name)`. Compared to Ruby string interpolation, this also has the advantage of ensuring that any untrusted parameters are properly escaped.

Comment: good point thanks ... thanks for considering my question seriously with so bad ' Punctuation' and 'Capitalisation' ...